# Insert rows for missing dates in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

the starting point is the following table in which entries are made for events on specific days (journal).

| Entity | Event | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123 | acquisition | 05.05.2015 | 10,000.00 |
| 0123 | capital increase | 30.11.2015 | 1,000.00 |
| 0123 | write-off | 31.12.2017 | -4,000.00 |
| 0123 | write-up | 31.12.2019 | 3,000.00 |

This journal is loaded into Power Query to be enhanced with additional information from other sources.

The goal is a Power Pivot table in which the amounts are summarized as at 31.12. of each year (Subtotals).

| Year | Entity | Event | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | 0123 | aquisition | 05.05.2015 | 10,000.00 |
| 2015 | 0123 | capital increase | 30.11.2015 | 1,000.00 |
| 2015 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 11,000.00 |
| 2016 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 11,000.00 |
| 2017 | 0123 | write-off | 31.12.2017 | -4,000.00 |
| 2017 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 7,000.00 |
| 2018 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 7,000.00 |
| 2019 | 0123 | write-up | 31.12.2019 | 3,000.00 |
| 2019 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 10,000.00 |
| 2020 Subtotal | 0123 |  |  | 10,000,00 |

The question is how to insert rows in Power Query for years where no activity (event) has occurred (no entry in the journal) so that a subtotal can be shown in Power Pivot as of 31.12. of each year.

I hope I could explain my issue in an understandable way. Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards,

Joerg

Comment: So you just want to add a row for each missing year with just the year column having data ?

Comment: In my example I would need rows with the dates 12/31/2016, 12/31/2018 and 12/31/2020 in the Date column. In order to make the reference to the entity, the corresponding entity must also be taken over in this line.

Comment: If there is another way to create the pivot table, then I am also grateful for hints.

Comment: If entity #1 max year is 2015 and entity #2 max year is 2018, are both supposed to fill dates through 2018, or is #1 only supposed to fill dates in 2015?     Is the date column text or date format?

Comment: That's a good question. I think the easiest way would be as follows: Last entered date (e.g. 10.05.2020) of the entire journal is used as last year end (in this case 31.12.2020).  If then an entity has already been disposed/sold in 2018 , then it will be reported as 0.00 as of 31.12.2018, 31.12.2019 and 31.12.2020. The date column is formatted as date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this works for you. There are shorter, more confusing ways to do it

Get minimum year of all the data, and maximum year of all the data, and create a table of all combinations of years and entities. See if those are being used. If not, merge that year and entity back into the original table with month=dec day=31

there is a bit of self-merging etc, which requires pasting this into home...advanced... since not all of it can be done in the user interface

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Entity", Int64.Type}, {"Event", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([Date])),

// Create table of all possible Entities and Years
DateList = {Date.Year(List.Min(#"Added Custom"[Date])) .. Date.Year(List.Max(#"Added Custom"[Date]))},
Entities = Table.AddColumn(Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Entity"})),"Year", each DateList),
#"Expanded Year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Entities, "Year"),

// Find unique Data and merge into original data set
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Year",{"Year", "Entity"},#"Added Custom",{"Year", "Entity"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Date"}, {"Date2"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([Date2] = null)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Date", each #date([Year],12,31), type date),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Date2", "Year"}),
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", #"Removed Columns" })

in #"Appended Query"
```

Comment: Wow... I tested it with the simplified example with one entity. It works!
In the pivot table, the years without movement are shown and the balances as of 31.12. are 
accumulated correctly per "running totals".

It also works in Power Query with more than one entity. The next challenge now is that the
year-end totals do not work properly when a filter is set on the entity. The rolling total
at year-end also sums the amounts of the hidden entities. But I think that is no issue of
Power Query but of the Pivot Table. Probably a DAX formula should help.

Thank you very much horseyride!!!